# SQL: Select MAC stored as bigint that contains part of a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big table with a few columns, one of them is the MAC address (primary key) stored as `UNSIGNED BIGINT`.
I would like to make a query to fetch the rows where the MAC contains parts of a string.

This is how I insert a row (mysql):

```
INSERT INTO mybigtable (mac, col2, col3) 
    VALUES (conv('0123456778AB', 16, 10), 'myval1', 'myval2')
```

How can I select the rows which MAC column contains the string '56'? This is my solution:

```
SELECT * from mybigtable WHERE HEX(mac) LIKE '%56%'
```

I feel this query performance is poor because it has to convert to hex all the rows of the table to compare the strings.

Is there a better way to make this query? I think about bitwise but I don't know how to do it. Do I need to change the type of the column? I don't like storing it as CHAR(12) because it is the PK and there are some FK involved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your primary goal is hard to optimize. The thing is - even with string column, searching with `%substring%` won't use key in general

Comment: Why do you store the MAC address as decimal and not as binary? This makes hardly sense to me and complicates this issue further.

Comment: @GhostGambler I can change the data type to binary if needed. Does that affect the performance of the primary key and foreign keys?.

Comment: I cannot tell. If it does, you can still use an arbitrary ID auto increment column as a replacement. Thing is: One hexadecimal character represents 4 bits in binary. A condition like `%56%` is then easily converted to `%01010110%`, while this cannot be done that easily with a decimal representation. Still the query itself won't be very fast, like @AlmaDo stated correctly. I do not see anything you can do to speed this up.